# ggplot2: Size and placement of geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the data for the plot that I am trying to modify:

```
mdfr <- read.table(textConnection("
 name stadio   variable      value rating
541B      1 start_date 22/02/2011      5
541B      2 start_date 24/05/2011      5
541B      3 start_date 01/06/2011      5
541B      4 start_date 20/09/2011      5
579B      1 start_date 07/06/2011      5
579B      2 start_date 08/02/2012      5
579B      3 start_date 09/02/2012      5
579B      4 start_date 24/04/2012      5
635B      1 start_date 03/05/2012      5
635B      2 start_date 29/06/2012      5
635B      3 start_date 05/07/2012      5
635B      4 start_date 11/09/2012      5
700B      1 start_date 29/02/2012      5
700B      2 start_date 29/02/2012      5
700B      3 start_date 29/02/2012      5
700B      4 start_date 08/05/2012      5
558B      1 start_date 30/05/2011      5
558B      2 start_date 17/10/2011      5
558B      3 start_date 27/01/2012      5
558B      4 start_date 06/04/2012      5
725B      1 start_date 28/12/2011      5
725B      2 start_date 23/02/2012      5
725B      3 start_date 02/03/2012      5
725B      4 start_date 31/05/2012      5
727B      1 start_date 23/12/2011      5
727B      2 start_date 03/02/2012      5
727B      3 start_date 16/02/2012      5
727B      4 start_date 18/05/2012      5
733B      1 start_date 30/12/2011      5
733B      2 start_date 23/02/2012      5
733B      3 start_date 02/03/2012      5
733B      4 start_date 07/06/2012      5
734B      1 start_date 16/03/2012      5
734B      2 start_date 16/03/2012      5
734B      3 start_date 16/03/2012      5
734B      4 start_date 25/04/2012      5
719B      1 start_date 29/06/2012      5
719B      2 start_date 10/07/2012      5
719B      3 start_date 19/07/2012      5
719B      4 start_date 16/10/2012      5
737B      1 start_date 22/06/2012      5
737B      2 start_date 25/07/2012      5
737B      3 start_date 01/08/2012      5
737B      4 start_date 23/10/2012      5
541A      1 start_date 22/02/2011      3
541A      2 start_date 24/05/2011      3
541A      3 start_date 01/06/2011      3
541A      4 start_date 20/09/2011      3
579A      1 start_date 07/06/2011      3
579A      2 start_date 08/02/2012      3
579A      3 start_date 09/02/2012      3
579A      4 start_date 08/05/2012      3
635A      1 start_date 03/05/2012      3
635A      2 start_date 31/07/2012      3
635A      3 start_date 31/07/2012      3
635A      4 start_date 23/10/2012      3
700A      1 start_date 22/03/2012      3
700A      2 start_date 22/03/2012      3
700A      3 start_date 22/03/2012      3
700A      4 start_date 12/06/2012      3
558A      1 start_date 30/05/2011      3
558A      2 start_date 17/10/2011      3
558A      3 start_date 27/01/2012      3
558A      4 start_date 06/04/2012      3
725A      1 start_date 28/12/2011      3
725A      2 start_date 23/02/2012      3
725A      3 start_date 02/03/2012      3
725A      4 start_date 31/05/2012      3
727A      1 start_date 23/12/2011      3
727A      2 start_date 03/02/2012      3
727A      3 start_date 16/02/2012      3
727A      4 start_date 18/05/2012      3
733A      1 start_date 30/12/2011      3
733A      2 start_date 23/02/2012      3
733A      3 start_date 02/03/2012      3
733A      4 start_date 07/06/2012      3
734A      1 start_date 16/03/2012      3
734A      2 start_date 16/03/2012      3
734A      3 start_date 16/03/2012      3
734A      4 start_date 25/04/2012      3
719A      1 start_date 10/07/2012      3
719A      2 start_date 17/07/2012      3
719A      3 start_date 26/07/2012      3
719A      4 start_date 09/10/2012      3
737A      1 start_date 01/07/2012      3
737A      2 start_date 06/07/2012      3
737A      3 start_date 26/07/2012      3
737A      4 start_date 16/10/2012      3
541B      1   end_date 24/05/2011      5
541B      2   end_date 01/06/2011      5
541B      3   end_date 20/09/2011      5
541B      4   end_date 28/09/2012      5
579B      1   end_date 08/02/2012      5
579B      2   end_date 09/02/2012      5
579B      3   end_date 24/04/2012      5
579B      4   end_date 29/10/2012      5
635B      1   end_date 29/06/2012      5
635B      2   end_date 05/07/2012      5
635B      3   end_date 11/09/2012      5
635B      4   end_date 04/02/2013      5
700B      1   end_date 29/02/2012      5
700B      2   end_date 29/02/2012      5
700B      3   end_date 08/05/2012      5
700B      4   end_date 12/11/2012      5
558B      1   end_date 17/10/2011      5
558B      2   end_date 27/01/2012      5
558B      3   end_date 06/04/2012      5
558B      4   end_date 09/09/2012      5
725B      1   end_date 23/02/2012      5
725B      2   end_date 02/03/2012      5
725B      3   end_date 31/05/2012      5
725B      4   end_date 30/11/2012      5
727B      1   end_date 03/02/2012      5
727B      2   end_date 16/02/2012      5
727B      3   end_date 18/05/2012      5
727B      4   end_date 19/11/2012      5
733B      1   end_date 23/02/2012      5
733B      2   end_date 02/03/2012      5
733B      3   end_date 07/06/2012      5
733B      4   end_date 30/11/2012      5
734B      1   end_date 16/03/2012      5
734B      2   end_date 16/03/2012      5
734B      3   end_date 25/04/2012      5
734B      4   end_date 04/07/2012      5
719B      1   end_date 10/07/2012      5
719B      2   end_date 19/07/2012      5
719B      3   end_date 16/10/2012      5
719B      4   end_date 28/02/2013      5
737B      1   end_date 25/07/2012      5
737B      2   end_date 01/08/2012      5
737B      3   end_date 23/10/2012      5
737B      4   end_date 28/02/2013      5
541A      1   end_date 24/05/2011      3
541A      2   end_date 01/06/2011      3
541A      3   end_date 20/09/2011      3
541A      4   end_date 17/01/2013      3
579A      1   end_date 08/02/2012      3
579A      2   end_date 09/02/2012      3
579A      3   end_date 08/05/2012      3
579A      4   end_date 19/12/2012      3
635A      1   end_date 31/07/2012      3
635A      2   end_date 31/07/2012      3
635A      3   end_date 23/10/2012      3
635A      4   end_date 22/03/2013      3
700A      1   end_date 22/03/2012      3
700A      2   end_date 22/03/2012      3
700A      3   end_date 12/06/2012      3
700A      4   end_date 18/12/2012      3
558A      1   end_date 17/10/2011      3
558A      2   end_date 27/01/2012      3
558A      3   end_date 06/04/2012      3
558A      4   end_date 10/01/2013      3
725A      1   end_date 23/02/2012      3
725A      2   end_date 02/03/2012      3
725A      3   end_date 31/05/2012      3
725A      4   end_date 30/11/2012      3
727A      1   end_date 03/02/2012      3
727A      2   end_date 16/02/2012      3
727A      3   end_date 18/05/2012      3
727A      4   end_date 19/11/2012      3
733A      1   end_date 23/02/2012      3
733A      2   end_date 02/03/2012      3
733A      3   end_date 07/06/2012      3
733A      4   end_date 30/11/2012      3
734A      1   end_date 16/03/2012      3
734A      2   end_date 16/03/2012      3
734A      3   end_date 25/04/2012      3
734A      4   end_date 20/09/2012      3
719A      1   end_date 17/07/2012      3
719A      2   end_date 26/07/2012      3
719A      3   end_date 09/10/2012      3
719A      4   end_date 21/12/2012      3
737A      1   end_date 06/07/2012      3
737A      2   end_date 26/07/2012      3
737A      3   end_date 16/10/2012      3
737A      4   end_date 28/12/2012      3
")->con,header=T);close(con)
```

I have created a plot using the following command

```
ggplot(mdfr, aes(as.Date(value, "%d/%m/%Y"), name, colour = factor(stadio))) +
    geom_line(size = 5) +
    xlab("") + ylab("") + labs(colour="Title") +
    scale_colour_brewer(pal="RdYlGn",breaks = c("1", "2", "3","4"), labels = c("Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3","Label 4"))
```

I need your help to do the following:

1. Change the size of the bars for the rows with names ending with an `A`. That is, instead of using `geom_line(size = 5)`, I would like the size to be equal to the value of variable `rating`, i.e. 5 for names ending in B and 3 for names ending in A.
2. Is it possible to make the bars that have the same number in their name to look like  pairs in order to look like having 11 pairs instead of 22 seperate ones? e.g. 737A to be closer to 737B than 734B. (so as and look like [that chart](http://support.sas.com/rnd/app/or/gifs/gantt_annotate2.gif)).
3. In case a second (or third) legend appears, how can I suppress the appearance of a selected legend? - because using `opts(legend.position = "none")` makes all of them invisible.
4. Why does this ggplot command generates an error in ggplot 0.9.1 while it is ok if I use ggplot 0.8.9? (Error in scale_map.discrete(scale, df[[j]]) :   attempt to apply non-function). How should I modify it?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I found out the problem in No 4. Instead of pal="RdYlGn" I should give palette="RdYlGn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, I had misread the first question

1) Use the rating with size as an aesthetic.

2) With the data you provided, the data is plotted that way but you can order it inside ggplot with order.

3) Use `guide = none` in the scale you want to remove.

```
ggplot(mdfr[order(mdfr$name),], aes(as.Date(value, "%d/%m/%Y"), name, colour = factor(stadio))) +
  geom_line(aes(size = as.factor(rating))) +
 labs(colour="Title", x = "", y = "") +
 scale_size_manual(breaks = c("3","5"), values = c(3,5), guide = "none")+
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="RdYlGn",breaks = c("1", "2", "3","4"), 
                      labels = c("Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3","Label 4"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. What kind of data would help me create the effect in no 2?

Answer (score 3):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

# This solves issue #2
mdfr <- mdfr[order(mdfr$name), ]

# This grabs the last letter (A or B)
mdfr$letter_size <- ifelse(str_sub(mdfr$name, start=-1)=="B", 5, 3)

# This solves #1 for you by scaling the size of the bar by letter.
# the scale_size() option removes it from the legend and solves #3.
ggplot(mdfr, aes(as.Date(value, "%d/%m/%Y"), name, colour = factor(stadio))) +
    geom_line(aes(size = mdfr$letter_size)) + 
    scale_size(guide="none") + 
    xlab("") + ylab("") + 
    labs(colour="Title")  + 
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn", breaks = c("1", "2", "3","4"), 
        labels = c("Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3","Label 4"))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but I dont want so much difference in width. I want the bars to be only a little narrower. But I can't do it. Thanks for scale_size(). scale_size_manual seems to do the trick (as I see in another answer). However it doesn't work in ggplot 0.8.9

Comment: Why not just update your version of `ggplot`? Is there some reason you have to use `0.8.9`?

Comment: You are wright. Is it by any means possible to use a different brewer palette for the thinner lines?