# about barplot for data with negative values

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to plot a stacked bar chart for a matrix of data containing both positive and negative values.

I used the code below and I was expecting all positive values stacked above x-axis and all negative values stacked below x-axis but this is not the case.

```
  test<-matrix(c(1,-2,-3,4,5,-6),ncol=2)
  colnames(test)=c("A","B")
  rownames(test)=c("x","y","z")
  barplot(test)
```

If I look at the `help` I can't find something about this specific topic.

Do I have to use some extra command or extra parameter to achieve that?

Comment: I'd like to plot positive and negative two separate stacked bars for the same column.

Comment: I think this is tricky: You could go with a [ggplot solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734368/ggplot2-and-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values) or  add `beside=TRUE` , but of course its not stacked.

Comment: Experiment with the argument `ylim` .

Comment: Do you know why it is trick with barplot? Worst case I can use 'barchart' from package 'lattice' that seems doing the job if no solution comes up.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft; can you expand on your comment please

Comment: Given Carl's comment I am probably missing something but it think you need to make two plots, one with pos counts and one with neg, and use the `add=T` parameter.

Comment: @user20650 that wouldn't hurt.  As to my previous comment -- the OP should *RTFM* -  the meaning of the optional arguments to `barplot` is provided in `?barplot` .

Comment: I am looking into ylim . The documentation says just 'ylim: limits for the y axis'. I do believe that it is hard to understand how this could help solving my problem but I'll keep on reading and investigating. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick (but not the best) workaround:

```
test1 <- test2 <- test
test1[test1<0] <- 0
test2[test2>0] <- 0
myrange <- c(min(colSums(test2)),max(colSums(test1)))
barplot(test1,ylim=myrange)
barplot(test2,add=TRUE,ylim=rev(myrange))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi xb! This works and it is ok for me.(and it adds few things I need to look at). Essentially you split the matrix in 2 parts: the negative and the positive and you combined together. I didn't even know that it was possible to do that. Thanks a lot for your help.