# stacked geom_bar issue with stacked bar and labels misplaced

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have this bar chart:

```
group = c("A","A","B","B")
value = c(25,-75,-40,-76)
day = c(1,2,1,2)
dat = data.frame(group = group , value = value, day = day)

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = factor(day))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value,0)), color = "black", position = "stack")
```

[image]

and I'd like the bars stacked and the values to show up.  When I run the code above the -76 is not in the correct location (and neither is the 75 it seems).

Any idea how to get the numbers to appear in the correct location?

Comment: You should pay attention to the warning: `Warning message:
Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0` i.e. you're making a confusing graph.

Comment: Why are you using `position = "identity"` in `geom_bar` if you want like the bars to be stacked?

Comment: Also @alistaire, I'm not getting that warning, running `2.1.0.9000`.

Comment: Yes I'd like the bars stacked

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=group, y=value, fill=factor(day))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity")+
    geom_text(label =round(value,0),color = "black")+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-80,-40,0))
```

[image]

Comment: OP would "like the bars stacked". If you disagree, you should at least explain that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stacking a mix of negative and positive values is difficult for ggplot2.  The easiest thing to do is to split the dataset into two, one for positives and one for negatives, and then add bar layers separately.  A classic example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734448/2461552).

You can do the same thing with the text, adding one text layer for the positive y values and one for the negatives.

```
dat1 = subset(dat, value >= 0)
dat2 = subset(dat, value < 0)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = group, y = value, fill = factor(day))) +
    geom_bar(data = dat1, stat = "identity", position = "stack")+
    geom_bar(data = dat2, stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
    geom_text(data = dat1, aes(label = round(value,0)), color = "black", position = "stack") +
    geom_text(data = dat2, aes(label = round(value,0)), color = "black", position = "stack")
```

[image]

If using the currently development version of ggplot2 (2.1.0.9000), the stacking doesn't seem to be working correctly in `geom_text` for negative values.  You can always calculate the text positions "by hand" if you need to.

```
library(dplyr)
dat2 = dat2 %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(pos = cumsum(value))

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = group, y = value, fill = factor(day))) +
    geom_bar(data = dat1, stat = "identity", position = "stack")+
    geom_bar(data = dat2, stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
    geom_text(data = dat1, aes(label = round(value,0)), color = "black") +
    geom_text(data = dat2, aes(label = round(value,0), y = pos), color = "black")
```