# ggplot2 stacked bar with negative values not working with Plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I tried the code in the answer in this previous thread, [ggplot2 and a Stacked Bar Chart with Negative Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734368/ggplot2-and-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values).

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   Division Year OperatingIncome
1  A  2012           11460
  2  B  2012            7431
  3  C  2012           -8121
  4  D  2012           15719
  5  E  2012             364
  6  A  2011           12211
  7  B  2011            6290
  8  C  2011           -2657
  9  D  2011           14657
  10 E  2011            1257
  11 A  2010           12895
  12 B  2010            5381
  13 C  2010           -2408
  14 D  2010           11849
  15 E  2010             517",header = TRUE,sep = "",row.names = 1)

dat1 <- subset(dat,OperatingIncome >= 0)
dat2 <- subset(dat,OperatingIncome < 0)
plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = dat1, aes(x=Year, y=OperatingIncome, fill=Division),stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = dat2, aes(x=Year, y=OperatingIncome, fill=Division),stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = 1)
ggplotly(plot)
```

Here is what I'm getting:

[image]

If I run `plot(plot)` then it works fine:

[image]

How do I fix the issue in Plotly?

Comment: try aes(x=as.factor(Year)....

Comment: It didn't work. It just changed my plotly label to say `as.factor(Year)`

Comment: Seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/560).

Comment: I'm using plotly 4.5.6 as well. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

**For future readers**

Nowadays, plotly (I am using `4.8.0`) supports stacked barcharts with negative values. In the `layout` you have to set `barmode=relative`. Moreover, you can also use the `ggplotly` functionality posted in the question.

```
plot_ly(dat, y=~OperatingIncome, x=~Year, type='bar', name=~Division, color =~Division, 
        colors='Blues', marker=list(line=list(width=1, color='lightgray'))) %>% 
  layout(barmode = 'relative')
```

Will return:

[image]