# Stacked area chart with negative numbers using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

The code below constructs a stacked area chart using ggplot. But the chart doesn't look correct. The series "Name2" is negative, but the negative values are not reflected in the other series. On the graph it looks like the cumulative sum of the series is 24, but it is actually 18.

How can I fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)

d_date <- Sys.Date()
          d_value_1 <- c(1,3,4,0,0)
d_value_2 <- c(-1,-2,-8,5,0)
d_value_3 <- c(5,5,4,2,0)

df_plot_1 <- data.frame("date" = seq(d_date, d_date + 4, 1),
                        "value" = cumsum(d_value_1),
                        "name" = "Name1")

df_plot_2 <- data.frame("date" = seq(d_date, d_date + 4, 1),
                        "value" = cumsum(d_value_2),
                        "name" = "Name2")

df_plot_3 <- data.frame("date" = seq(d_date, d_date + 4, 1),
                        "value" = cumsum(d_value_3),
                        "name" = "Name3")

df_plot <- rbind(df_plot_1, df_plot_2, df_plot_3)


ggplot(df_plot, aes(x=date, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_area()
```

Comment: What are you hoping to get? Negative values cannot be stacked.

Comment: @CMichael On the graph it looks like the cumulative sum of the series is 24, but it is actually 18.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734368/ggplot2-and-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values