# Create a stacked column chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked column chart using R.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

Data `df`:

```
structure(list(Period = c("1971-1989", "1990-1999", "2000-2009", 
"2010-2019", "2020-2029"), Cold = c(-1.02, -0.3, -0.13, 0, 0.09
), Heat = c(6.08, -0.4, -0.1, 0, 0.17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Period is chr, the others are num.
I want to produce a stacked column chart that looks like this: (I made this using Excel)

[image]

I tried using `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=cold, y=heat, x=Period)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

But I couldn't get a stacked plot like I wanted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734368/ggplot2-and-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First transform the wide data.frame to long form, then use basically what you did before:

```
df <- structure(list(Period = c("1971-1989", "1990-1999", "2000-2009", 
"2010-2019", "2020-2029"), Cold = c(-1.02, -0.3, -0.13, 0, 0.09
), Heat = c(6.08, -0.4, -0.1, 0, 0.17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Period, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 45)) # rotate x-axis label by 45°
```

[image]

From here you can now modify axis and labels as desired.