# How to change where horizontal axis cross in geom_bar (ggplot2) for each bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following bar graph. Now each bar crosses the vertical axis at 0.

[image: current image]

I want to change where each bar crosses the vertical axis to a different place. Like the one below. For example, the first bar crosses at 0.02, the second bar crosses at -.08.
I understand that if you want to change where all bars cross to say 0.5, you just shift the axis label to 0.5. However, I want to change each bar to a different place. How do you do that?
[image: desired image]

Comment: It appears you are after (flipped) floating bar charts. Can you get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312189/floating-barcharts to work for you?

Comment: Otherwise please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data and make it clear how you want to shift each bar.